# About the notation of $2$D Laplace operator

Tags: notation, fourier-transform, convolution, laplacian, graph-laplacian

I’m reading a paper on [$2$D discrete Laplace operator](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1928&context=cstech), and perhaps because it’s an old paper, the notation in it really bothers me a lot. So can someone please explain it to me? For example, the notation I have highlighted in red line in the screenshot, such as what $G$ and $\log R$ mean and how to interpret these equations?

[image]

Comment: The $R$ is given at the bottom of the page at least, it's defined by $R^2 := j^2 + k^2$ (and taking the square root, since $\log$ is applied to $R$).

Comment: Is there something unclear about this question? Why get a vote down here?

Comment: @BrunoB Of course the literal meaning here is very clear, (it's like someone doesn't understand the role of the square root in a formula, you explain that we take the square root of it, someone ask what is the meaning of a product here, you explain that we need to multiply the two values together)  but I don't know how it's pulled out for example is this the fourier transform method, or give me some clues about the derivation.?

Comment: I did not downvote, I don't like unexplained downvoting unless it's a spam/actual nonsense post, but I think you might have more success if you explain (or show a reference of) what notations you *are* used to, as that might facilitate other users in helping you. It is my bad for thinking you didn't understand what the notations were defined as in the paper itself, I am sorry, but I thought light feedback would be better than no feedback, even if I know nothing about discrete Laplace operators. Hoping you'll find the information you need at some point, have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

This paper leaves out so many details that it's understandable that the notation doesn't make sense. The context here is that we want to study functions on the two-dimensional integer lattice $\mathbb Z^2$.
In particular, $G$ denotes a real-valued function on $\mathbb Z^2$, where $G_{i,j}$ denotes the value of the function at $(i,j) \in \mathbb Z^2$.

Rather than a single function $G$, this paper studies a family $G(\alpha)$ of functions on $\mathbb Z^2$ parametrized by $\alpha$.
So now $G_{i,j}(\alpha)$ denotes the value of the function $G(\alpha)$ at the lattice point $(i, j)$.
The function $G_\alpha$ is defined by (1a) to be a "fundamental solution" to a certain Laplacian operator $\mathbf L_\alpha$.
In general, a function that satisfies this type of relation to a Laplacian operator is known as a [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) which explains the choice of notation $G$.

The family of operators $\mathbf L_\alpha$ is a modification of the usual [Discrete graph Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator) $\mathbf L = \mathbf L_0$
on $\mathbb Z^2$ with nearest-neighbor edges.
There has been a lot of work on studying the Green's function for this Laplacian, e.g. Malik Mamode, [Revisiting the discrete planar Laplacian: exact results for the lattice Green function and continuum limit](https://hal.science/hal-03204762/document).